# Troubleshooting" ValueError: Index Date Invalid"?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning Python 3.7.4 using IDLE. I am receiving an error saying index date invalid.

I've had success using excel files that i've formatted with dates & data in individual col's (A-C) but this is a csv file with all the data in one col separated by commas. In the format with the data formatted i would use the below...

```
ANTM = pd.read_csv(r'C:\..\ANTM_stock'.csv', parse_dates= True, index_col=0)
```

I'm pretty sure the parse_dates=True, index_col=0 is indicating look at the first col & interpret them as dates. This works fine.

```
#Markowitz efficient frontier

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

companies = ['WMT','FB']
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\...\Walmart_FB_2014_2017.csv', index_col='Date')

df.head()
```

I expected to see a table with some data instead i received the error below.

```
ValueError: Index Date invalid
```

Below is a sample of the data (It is all in Col A)

[Data in CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkdA7.png)

Comment: Why the line number 9 is surrounded by single quotes?

Comment: A small sample of the data in the file may help

Comment: the single quote are from me trying to get it to post as a code snippet. it spanned more than 1 line and i wasnt able to get the parts in the lower line to show as code snippet so i was trying things and forgot to remove them. In the end i just shortened the line so it would all be in the box

Comment: Please provide a sample data, with that your code can be run to reproduce the error.

Comment: @xzcvb33 Your code runs fine for me. What happens if you try and read the csv without specifying the index column `df = pd.read_csv("...2017.csv")` and then setting the index to be "Date" `df.set_index("Date")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@xzcvb33 Your code runs fine for me. What happens if you try and read the csv without specifying the index column df = pd.read_csv("...2017.csv") and then setting the index to be "Date" df.set_index("Date")? – Tom yesterday